# Could someone explain the example below regarding JavaScript's concat() and slice() methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, concatenation

I understand concat() and slice() methods but I can't seem to grasp this example, please help!

```
function remove(array, index) {
  return array.slice(0, index)
    .concat(array.slice(index + 1));
}
console.log(remove(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], 2));
// → ["a", "b", "d", "e"]
```

Excerpt From: Marijn Haverbeke. “Eloquent JavaScript.” Apple Books.

Comment: You are slicing the first <index> items and the last <index-1> items, then merging them together into one array. The item in the middle, the one not in either of those slices, gets removed.

Comment: So which parts of the code do you understand? And what part exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi "*the last <index-1> items*" should be "the items after index+1", and I'd say "concatenated" not "merged" (which is a set operation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to understand a complex string of linked together function calls it can be helpful to break them out into separate lines and evaluate what they do one at a time. Javascript process calls from right to left:

```
    array.slice(index + 1) // ["d", "e"]
    .concat() // join the previous call's array with the next call
    array.slice(0, index) //  ["a", "b"]
    result ["a","b","d","e"]
```

I hope this helps explain the calls and what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
array.slice(0, index) // ['a','b']
array.slice(index + 1) // ['d','e']

//then

.concat //they are getting concatinated

[ 'a', 'b', 'd', 'e' ]
```